# Install nodejs 4 on redhat

Tags: linux, node.js, redhat

Nodejs version 4 has been released and installed on my windows machine.
I'm trying to install the package trough yum on redhat but i'm not getting the latest version.

i tried: `sudo yum install -y nodejs` but the lastest 4.0 version is not installed.

How do i install nodejs 4.0 on a redhat machine?

Answer (score 5):

NodeJS 4.X for EL7 repos located at https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/

To install with yum change baseurl in nodesource-el.repo file to:

```
baseurl=https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/$basearch
```

`/etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el.repo` content:

```
[nodesource]
name=Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/NODESOURCE-GPG-SIGNING-KEY-EL

[nodesource-source]
name=Node.js for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/SRPMS
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/NODESOURCE-GPG-SIGNING-KEY-EL
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: On Centos7 after adding the repo above, I run `yum list nodejs` and I see "5.4.0-1nodesource.el7.centos", i.e. a version 5 package instead of a version 4 package. Am I missing something here? Is v4 compatible with Centos 7?

Comment: For what it's worth I was able to fix my problem in the comment above by running `yum clean all`.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile and install from its source.

```
ver=4.0.0
wget -c https://nodejs.org/dist/v$ver/node-v$ver.tar.gz #This is to download the source code.
tar -xzf node-v$ver.tar.gz
cd node-v$ver
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installation

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried without succes. I also tried the git version.
the 'make' command gives me errors: 

In file included from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:29,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc:5:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()’:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:353: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

And many other errors. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install n -g` and then `n latest` for downloading it with this version manager.

**Edit:**
The [official distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) are managed by [Nodesource](https://nodesource.com/). For RHEL the setup is supposed to be (take from the repo):

**Current instructions for installing, as listed on the [Node.js Wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager):**

Note that the Node.js packages for EL 5 (RHEL5 and CentOS 5) depend on the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository being available. The setup script will check and provide instructions if it is not installed.

Run as root on RHEL, CentOS, CloudLinux or Fedora:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

Then install, as root:

```
yum install -y nodejs
```

> But be aware that 4.0 is currently **not** in their **rpm** distribution

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its a solution but i want to use the default "node"  command. Any idea?

Comment: I see. I added the link to the nodesource dist which is the official one. But be aware that rpm only supports 0.12 and I guess yum just wraps rpm on RHEL (educated guess).

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution and it worked:

Distrubution url: Distr: https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1.tar.gz (v4.2.1 for now)

Unpack the package (tar Jxf node-v4.2.1.tar.xz).

Some package could be too old and will cause problems during installation.
cd to the unpacked file and run ”./configure”. if the warming “C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4” is displayed you need to execute the following commands:

```
curl http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/scl/slc6-scl.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-scl.repo

rpm --import http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/51/i386/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern

yum install -y devtoolset-3
```

And to utilize it without having to set environment variables execute this command:

```
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

Now restart the process:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

First, update software repository to the latest versions:

```
yum -y update
```

Intall "Development Tools". It's a group of tools for compiling software from sources.

```
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Move to /usr/src directory - the usual place to hold software sources.

```
cd /usr/src
```

Now, we pick the latest compressed source archive from Node.js website at http://nodejs.org/download/.

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.4/node-v4.2.4.tar.gz

tar zxf node-v4.2.4.tar.gz
cd node-v4.2.4
./configure
make
make install
```